# To get the value into variable from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

when any number is clicked corresponding horizontal and vertical value should be store into variable.
example when any number is clicked it should give its unique matrix value.
using jquery value can be feth but it has hide and show property which is giving problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myselection').on('change', function() {
    var demovalue = $(this).val();
    $("#showOne").hide();
    $("div.myDiv").hide();
    $("#show" + demovalue).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  display: none;
}

#showOne {}

#showTwo {}

#showThree {}

#showfour {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<table style="width:80%" id="customers" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color: white;"></th>
    <th colspan="2"> sdfv</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <select class="ui dropdown" id="myselection">
        <option value="One">type</option>
        <option value="Two">value</option>
        <option value="Three">dsf</option>
        <option value="four">tyir</option>
      </select>
    </th>
    <th>htrt</th>
    <th>xmcv</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="showOne">
  <table style="width:80%" id="customers" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>sdfg</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>dfv-Pacfvc</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Europe</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>India</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MENA</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>North America</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>South America</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="showThree" class="myDiv">
  <table style="width:80%" id="customers" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>To be closed</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Stop provisioning</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>In Service</td>
      <td>132</td>
      <td>127</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>In Progress</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Future</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Full</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="showfour" class="myDiv">
  <table style="width:80%" id="customers" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Access</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Core</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FPAccess</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Major</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Partner</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your description doesn't explain all the things.

Comment: when a number value is clicked it should give the location ie Rindex TopIndex ie for 7 it should return 1:1 for 8 it should return 1:2

Comment: row and column values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the relative index from the given `<td>` and `<tr>` respectively.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#myselection').on('change', function() {
    var demovalue = $(this).val();
    $("#showOne").hide();
    $("div.myDiv").hide();
    $("#show" + demovalue).show();
  });
  
  $('#customers tr td').click(function(event) {
    const colIndex = $(this).index();
    const rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    alert(`Row: ${rowIndex} , Column: ${colIndex}`);
  });
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<table style="width:80%" id="customers" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color: white;"></th>
    <th colspan="2"> sdfv</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <select class="ui dropdown" id="myselection">
        <option value="One">type</option>
        <option value="Two">value</option>
        <option value="Three">dsf</option>
        <option value="four">tyir</option>
      </select>
    </th>
    <th>htrt</th>
    <th>xmcv</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="showOne">
  <table style="width:80%" id="customers" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>sdfg</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>dfv-Pacfvc</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Europe</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>India</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MENA</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>North America</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>South America</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="showThree" class="myDiv">
  <table style="width:80%" id="customers" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>To be closed</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Stop provisioning</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>In Service</td>
      <td>132</td>
      <td>127</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>In Progress</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Future</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Full</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="showfour" class="myDiv">
  <table style="width:80%" id="customers" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Access</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Core</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FPAccess</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Major</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Partner</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```